# Cannot resolve symbol 'window' error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

When I add `"this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);"` to my activity, IDE redden **'Window'** word and on tooltip it warns me by **"cannot resolve symbol 'window'"**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Add "import android.view.Window;"  to resolve this issue

Comment: @AmritPalSingh Thanks, please write it as an answer so I mark it.

Comment: glad that it worked for you .. :) done posting it as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `import android.view.Window;` to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold `ctrl` key ( `command` on MAC ) and click on `'window'` text . A `orange bulb` will show up on the left panel , click on it , it will ask you to `import` necessary module .